# How to return observable after all values of first observable are emmitted?

Tags: rx-java

I have a method that creates an observable from list of strings.

```
public Observable makeUrls() {
    List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
    return Observable.from(urls)
            .flatMap(url -> upload(url));
}
```

Now I want to return method b after all values in the list is emitted.

```
public Observable b(List<String> strings){
    return Observable.from(strings)
                     ..some other work here...;
}
```

The expected code i need is something like this:

```
public Observable makeUrls() {
    List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
    return Observable.from(urls)
            .flatMap(url -> upload(url))
            // This part is what i can't figure out how to write...
            // I want to call this after all items are emitted but I can't return Observable
            .doOnCompleted(()->b(strings));
}
```

Comment: What is "strings"? If this your original urls or a collection of your return value from upload(String url)?

Answer (score 4):

Use `.ignoreElements` and `concatWith`:

Suppose `b(strings)` returns `Observable<Thing>`:

```
return Observable.from(urls)
        .flatMap(url -> upload(url))
        .ignoreElements()
        .castAs(Thing.class)
        .concatWith(b(strings));
```

Comment: Ok I've updated it with my guess. Can you refine the question so we know what the signature of b is for starters and where strings comes from?

Comment: ok good. Yeah toList works if you need to do stuff with all the emissions but that wasn't clear from the question. Should I leave the answer as is or shall we clean up question and answer?